# How to Select .zip file from Documents/Inbox/ in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

How to select zip file from Documents/Inbox/ directory. Also give reference of selected file to variable.

```
let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager()
    let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: NSHomeDirectory())
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        print("Files::",file)
} 

o/p:  
 Files:: Documents/Inbox
 Files:: Documents/Inbox/abc.zip
 Files:: Documents/Inbox/pqrs.zip
 Files:: Documents/Inbox/xyz.zip
 Files:: Library
 Files:: Library/Caches
 Files:: Library/Caches/Snapshots
 Files:: Library/Preferences
```

i need to select zip file from this list.

Comment: You will have to apply predicate and set correct path for getting .zip files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swift 3

```
    let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager()
    let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: NSHomeDirectory())
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {

        //print("Files::",file)

        if (String(describing: file).characters.count >= 4){

            let fileName = file as! String

            if fileName.substring(from:fileName.index(fileName.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)) == ".zip"{

                print((file as! NSString).lastPathComponent)
                self.arrayZipfile.append((file as! NSString).lastPathComponent)
            }
        }
    }
```

select arrayZipFile index.